# Is there a Django setting to generate multiple_words table names for MultipleWords models?

Tags: django, django-models

Given an example app called `x_y` with a model called `FooBar` the generated table name is `x_y_foobar` rather than the expected `x_y_foo_bar`. This makes it harder to read and distinguish table names, especially with long names. Is there a global setting that I can use so I *don't* have to set each table name manually?

PS: I would be fine with model names like `TLA` ending up as `t_l_a` in the table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the model's metaclass by subclassing `ModelBase`:

```
import re
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class ModelMetaClass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(ModelMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class._meta.db_table = new_class._meta.app_label + '_' + '_'.join(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]*', name)))
        return new_class
```

Then in your model:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = ModelMetaClass

    class Meta:
        pass
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to set the default `__metaclass__` for all models? Otherwise I could just subclass `models.Model` and use that everywhere.

Comment: Pretty sure you can simply make `FooBar` an abstract class and let all of your real models subclass `FooBar`.